# Change visual studio language in command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, localization

I've a computer with Windows localized in Italian language.

I've installed Visual Studio 2022, and I've set the language in English; after the restart, I can see the Visual Studio IDE in English language, and that's good.

But I need to use visual studio also from command line. When I start the `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` of Visual Studio, I can see that the compiler errors are in Italian language rather than English.

How can I set the English language also for the command line?

Answer (score 0):

To change the `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS` display language, you need to modify your Visual Studio installation. To do so,

- open the Visual Studio Installer,
- locate the version of the build tools you use and,
- click on "modify".

One of the available tabs should be "Language Packs". From there you can

- uncheck the Italian language box
- check the English language box

When you relaunch your command prompt, it should now be in English.